# Grand-children of CSS grid overflows container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with a fixed height, and I need to make one of the grand-children scrollable.

Everything is fine if I set `height: 100%; overflow: auto` on the direct child of the grid. However I need a deeply nested child to be scrollable, rather than the direct child:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="direct-child">
    <div class="another-one">
      <div class="make-this-scrollable"> <--
```

I tried to "propagate" the height (set `height: 100%` on all elements in the tree) set `min-height: 0`, set `minxmax(0, 1fr)` for the template-row of the grid but nothing works, the content of `.make-this-scrollable` always overflows (the computed height of all elements is equal to the content height, except the grid).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Simply add some ```height``` and ```overflow-y: scroll``` to the ```div``` you want to be scrollable. But the ```div``` can only become scrollable when the content inside that ```div``` is larger than it's ```height```.

Comment: @YashSharma that is one of the things I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with another `min-height: 0`. My problem was that `.direct-child` was itself a CSS grid, and I needed `min-height: 0` on `.another-one` as well to allow the element to shrink below the content height.

```css
.grid {
  height: 80vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.direct-child {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  display: grid;
  background-color: slateblue;
}

.another-one {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}

.make-this-scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="direct-child">
    <div class="another-one">
      <div class="make-this-scrollable">
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
            <li>item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```